# Data Validation list to add multiple item, comma seperated in the same list excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, data-validation

Ok, so I have a list of categories in sheet 'categories' (column A - with a header in row 1 - it goes down to row 72 - I have called this list 'categories' as well)

in sheet 1 'Productlist' column D i would like to have a data validation list that has a dropdown where you can select multiple items and they would be entered into the same cell (column D) seperated by a comma.

I have managed to make a dropdown where you can select 1 product, but I am a complete beginner and am completely lost.

There is another question with one answer here directing you to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rH8N-Puvbo and http://www.contextures.com/excelfiles.html#DataVal but the files don't work in excel 2013.

Can anyone advise how to do this?